# redirect issue with mod rewrite in vhost.config for a single domain

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, rewrite, virtualhost

We are on a Network Solutions VPS, four domains all one IP.

In vhost.config file for a single domain, the following will work:

```
Redirect 301 /1234 http://example.com/
```

But the following 3 rewrites will not work:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^1234$ / [R=301,L]

Options +FollowSymlinks 
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^1234$ / [R=301,L]

Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^1234$ http://example.com [R=301,L]
```

These are just tests to get something more serious done with mod rewrite in vhost.config.
I feel like I must just be missing something simple. If anyone can help me out, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried adding a leading slash?  i.e., `RewriteRule ^/1234$`?

Comment: Why would I try that ? :)  Seriously thanks, works like a charm, and I appreciate the help.

Comment: Yeah, Apache can be a little weird... it doesn't explicitly say it in the docs, but its one of those "gotchas" that only makes sense AFTER you figure it out. :)  I added this as an answer so you can resolve the question.

Answer (score 0):

Adding answer from my comment.  Adding a leading slash makes it match the full path from the base, as opposed to a path component.